# Why can't I access array inside forEach() in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm not sure why i can't access the `allSubIABs` array inside `forEach`.
I can access the string `newCheckState` fine.

```
const newIABs = { ...this.state.iabs }
let allSubIABs = []
let newCheckState = 'asdasdasd'

console.log(typeof allSubIABs, allSubIABs)
Object.keys(newIABs).forEach(firstLevelIABCode => {
  console.log(newCheckState)
  console.log(typeof allSubIABs, allSubIABs)
  let allSubIABs = allSubIABs.concat(newIABs[firstLevelIABCode].children)
})
```

Output:

```
object []
asdasdasd
undefined undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
```

Comment: What do you get from `console.log( newIABS )` or `console.log( Object.keys( newIABS ) )`? I'm asking only because I've never seen the spread operator used to create an Object, only to populate an Array.

Comment: I'm actually going to mutate it later on in the code, thanks all for answering this dumb question I had lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `let allSubIABs` declaration declares a new variable whose default value is `undefined`, and this new variable shadows access to the outer `allSubIABs` with the same name.

You can see how hoisting affects your function. This code is equivalent to your own:

```
Object.keys(newIABs).forEach(firstLevelIABCode => {
  let allSubIABs;

  console.log(newCheckState)
  console.log(typeof allSubIABs, allSubIABs)
  allSubIABs = allSubIABs.concat(newIABs[firstLevelIABCode].children)
})
```

As you can see, variable declarations happen first (this is what "hoisting" means) and newly-declared variables hold the value `undefined` until assigned a value.

Consider analogously `var a = a.foo;` which produces the error `Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined` because `a` does exists as a variable, but it has never been given a value.

Since you actually want to access the outer `allSubIABs` variable, do not declare a new variable with `let`. This will cause `allSubIABs` variable tokens to refer to the nearest outer-scope variable of that name, which is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `let` declaration in the callback hides the outer `allSubIABs` declaration. Just get rid of that `let`.

Comment: Worth explaining what's happening here. I.e., the fact that, even though `allSubIABs` is referenced in the 2nd `console.log` within the `forEach` callback, it's re-declared in the line below that. JavaScript will hoist the declaration to the top of the scope, which effectively "resets" the value of that variable.